# NSDictionary...code works fine when run on simulator but not when run on device

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

I have a code where if the user makes a certain touch gesture, three UIImageViews will change its image according to which gesture was made.

I do this by having an NSDictionary made to associate certain gestures with certain images. 
I put an NSLog so it prints the address of the image it is displaying.

When I run it on a simulator, it works....the images show on screen and NSLog prints out the address of the image. But when I run it on my device, the images do not show on screen and NSLog prints null.

Any idea why this is happening??

Comment: Make sure to use the exact same casing for the filenames. Simulator running on OS X is default case insensitive but iOS on device is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are the images stored? Are they packaged with the bundle?